# How do I make the jspPane in jscrollpane 100% width

Tags: html, jscrollpane, scroller

I am trying to use jscrollpane for my website and change the default body scrollbar, but then the jspPane scrollbar was not 100% which changed the layout of my page. My page header and footer are all of 100% width and i want to change the jspPane width as such so that everything is stable. If jspPane is not suitable for my work, then what other scroller can i use. Thank you.

Comment: post an [sscce](http://sscce.org/). It isn't clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a old question but I ended up just manually triggering it to be 100%. Throw this into where you trigger the jscrollpane.

```
$(document).find('.jspPane').css('width','100%');
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a option 'autoReinitialise' and set to true.

```
$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane({autoReinitialise: true});
```

At-te;